# IIS recovery script on ping failure

Tags: iis

we have running webapp on IIS. Sometimes IIS does not respond to ping and we have to restart it manually.

Can you help me with recovery script doing these steps after ping related hangs occurs:

1. create full dump of IIS and WAS process
2. restart IIS
3. send email or write event to windows log

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will *help* you by pointing you in the right direction using powershell.

- Test-Connection can be used to return a boolean value on ping failure. Use an if statement on failure to
- Take your dumps somehow.
- iisreset
- Write-EventLog command
- Send-MailMessage command.

If you want a better answer, show some initiative and post your code.

Comment: Thank you, we have only 1 app on IIS named PROD, dump should be created on iis a was processes. Can you show me powershell script with pseudo parts please?